Google Analytics returns 500 when creating new access bindings for service accounts
Google analytics returns status code 500 when trying to add a new service account email.
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: <response-batch<id>@googleapis.com>

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

I have tried adding the emails both on the web dashboard (account access management and property access management tabs), as well as using the Analytics Admin SDK.
I have also tried using other GCP projects. For some reason, the error only happens for service accounts that belong to a newly-created GCP project. Adding new service accounts from a GCP project that i created ~1 year ago works as expected without error.
Does anyone know what might be the issue?
